# Spring Boot: Prevent persisting field declared in superclass

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a Todo app in Spring Boot and I need to create two tables: `Task` and `Todo`(`Todo` extends `Task`).

In `Task` table is a field called `description` and I would like to prevent that column to be created in `Todo` table.

How can I do it?

**Task(parent):**

```
package com.example.todo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Task {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

**Todo(child):**

```
package com.example.todo.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Todo extends Task {

    private boolean isChecked;
}
```

Comment: Essentially you are indicating that you have two types of Task entities. One with a description and one with a completion (isChecked). If this is the case then you should model it the same way in  your code base by creating a new class which inherits from Task and adds the description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you clean up your design because concrete classes inheriting from other concrete classes is (often) a code smell. The proper solution to this is to factor out the common parts of both classes into a (abstract) super class and then add the specific fields to the concrete inheriting classes:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Completable {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Task extends Completable {

    private String description;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Todo extends Completable {

    private boolean isChecked;
}
```

so you have the behaviour grouped in the classes where it belongs and don't have to make sure that one thing contains a description while it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

What you want cannot be done easily. But you might be trying to solve an issue in the wrong way.

From what I am reading you have a `Task` entity with has two separate types:

- one with a checkbox indicating its completion
- one with an additional description

If this is the case you might want to model the classes the same way. Thus having:

- A `Task` entity without the description
- A `Todo` entity extending `Task` with the checkbox
- A new `SummaryTask` extending `Task` with a description field